# ANTLR4 store all tokens in specific channel

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a lexer which puts every token the parser is interested in into the default channel and all comment-tokens in channel 1.

The default channel is used to create the actual tree while the comment channel is used to seperate the tokens and to store all comments.

Look at this scribble:
[image]

In chapter 12.1 p. 206-208 in The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference there is a comparable situation where comment tokens are shifted inside the token stream. The represented approach is to read out the comment-channel in an exit-method inside the parser.

In my opinion this is a very rough option for my problem, because i don't want to overwhelm my listener with that back-looking operations. Is there a possibility to  override a method which puts tokens inside the comment-channel?

Comment: What have you tried?  Lexer grammar?  What exact result are you seeking?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misunderstand how channels work in ANTLR. What happens is that the lexer, as it comes along a token, assigns the default channel (just a number) during initialization of the token. That value is only changed when the lexer finds a `-> channel()` command or you change it explicitely in a lexer action. So there is nothing to do in a listener or whatever to filter out such tokens.

Later when you want to get all tokens "in" a given channel (i.e. all tokens that have a specific channel number assigned) you can just iterate over all tokens returned by your token stream and compare the channel value. Alternatively you can create a new `CommonTokenStream` instance and pass it the channel your are interested in. It will then only give you those tokens from that channel (it uses a token source, e.g. a lexer, to get the actual tokens and cache them).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. You are right that there are no real physical channels, but numbers the tokens are labeled with. There is a possibility that you can also alias them in your lexer. That is what i acutally did. So think about channel 0 for default and 1 for comment.

That works perfect:
var tokens = commonTokenStream.GetTokens();
var commentTokens = tokens.Where(token => token.Channel == 1);

But i am a bit worry about that CommonTokenStream is a Stream. Will it never be flushed? And linear searches have bad performance havn't they?

Comment: The token stream is not an OS stream. It's basically a cache for all tokens that were produced by the lexer. The lexer always has only one token (the on it is currently working with). The common token stream keeps a list in memory to allow easy seek/look around. Iterating of that list is almost instantaneous. No need to keep yet another list for tokens on specific channels.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that there is a easy way to override how tokens are created. To do this, one can override a method inside the **CommonTokenFactory** and give it to the Lexer. At this point i can check the channel and i am able to push the tokens in a separate set.

In my opinion this is a little bit hacky, but i do not need to iterate over the whole commonTokenStream later on.

This code is only to demonstrate the idea behind (in C#) .

```
internal class HeadAnalyzer
{
    #region Methods

    internal void AnalyzeHeader(Stream headerSourceStream)
    {
        var antlrFileStream =
            new AntlrInputStream(headerSourceStream);
        var mcrLexer = new MCRLexer(antlrFileStream);

        var commentSaverTokenFactory = new MyTokenFactory();
        mcrLexer.TokenFactory = commentSaverTokenFactory;
        var commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(mcrLexer);

        var mcrParser = new MCRParser(commonTokenStream);
        mcrParser.AddErrorListener(new DefaultErrorListener());

        MCRParser.ProgramContext tree;
        try
        {
            tree = mcrParser.program(); // create the tree
        }
        catch (SyntaxErrorException syntaxErrorException)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        var headerContext = new HeaderContext();
        var headListener = new HeadListener(headerContext);
        ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(headListener, tree);

        var comments = commentSaverTokenFactory.CommentTokens; // contains all comments :)
    }

    #endregion
}

internal class MyTokenFactory : CommonTokenFactory
{
    internal readonly List<CommonToken> CommentTokens = new List<CommonToken>();

    public override CommonToken Create(Tuple<ITokenSource, ICharStream> source, int type, string text, int channel, int start, int stop, int line, int charPositionInLine)
    {
        var token =  base.Create(source, type, text, channel, start, stop, line, charPositionInLine);
        if (token.Channel == 1)
        {
            CommentTokens.Add(token);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Maybe there are some better approaches. For my usecase it works as expected.